# Filling up a vector

Tags: r

```
a <- c(0,3,7,2) 
b <- 10`
```

I  try to distribute a certain number of values (b) over the length of vector a. Instead of adding 10/4 to every value of a, I want to fill them up. the result vector for this case should be c(5,5,7,5).

what I've tried:

```
f = e + b
opt.vert <- function(b,a,f) {
  repeat{lapply(1:length(a),
               function(x) if((a[[x]] == min(a)) && (a[[x]]) < (b/length(a))){
                  a[[x]] <- a[[x]] +1
                } else {
                  a[[x]] <- a[[x]]
                } )
    if(sum(a) >= f) break
  }
  return(a)
}
```

Apart from that approach being horribly unelegant, it also doesn't work. I'm having a hard time figuring out what's wrong in it bc it seems to drag me into an eternal loop and I therefore get no error message.

Comment: The idea is so add +1 to the smallest number(s) of the vector, until b is completely distributed.

Comment: Possible without looping : mean to reach   `M = (sum(a)+10)/length(a) `
update when value  < M   `a[a<M] <- (b+ sum(a[a<M]))/length(a[a<M])  `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (i in seq_len(b)) a[which.min(a)] <- a[which.min(a)] + 1
#[1] 5 5 7 5
```

Note that `which.min` returns the position of the first minimum. If you want to break ties differently, you'll have to modify this slightly.

(I suspect spending some time on the mathematical background of the task might lead to more efficient solutions that could avoid loops. Might be a nice puzzle for people with more spare time.)

Answer (score 1):

something like this using recursion

```
a <- c(0, 3, 7, 2)
b <- 10
Reduce(function(x, y) {
    idx <- which.min(x)
    x[idx] <- x[idx] + 1
    x
}, rep(1, b), a, accumulate=TRUE)
```